# Access VBA: Cannot combine variable and string in SQL query

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, vba

I have a list of users (as string variable) and want to use it as the criteria (one user at a time) for my SQL to pick the first item's code. So I put a SQL query as a string to run it later in the code.

I've tried this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Item.Code FROM Item WHERE Item.User = '" 
strSQL = strSQL & strUserName & "' ORDER BY ID DESC"
```

If the strUserName = "A-user" for example, I only get this SQL string, according to "Quick Watch...":

```
SELECT TOP 1 Item.Code FROM Item WHERE Item.User = 'A-user
```

The part with `"' ORDER BY ID DESC"` isn't included in the SQL string at all!

And for running the SQL query by using `"Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)"`, I get this error:

> Run-time error '3075':
>   Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Item.User = "A-user"

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please show more of your code as the concatenation of your strings should work according to the currently shown code. However, building a SQL statement like so is the classic way of SQL injection ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how your code triggers that 3075 error.  However I would use a parameter query instead.  That way you can avoid problems with quoted values in your SQL statement.

```vb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSelect As String
Dim strUserName As String

strUserName = "A-user"
strSelect = "SELECT TOP 1 i.Code FROM [Item] AS i WHERE i.User = [which_user] ORDER BY i.ID DESC"
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
qdf.Parameters("which_user").Value = strUserName
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: Thanks! I still have some question regarding your answer.
The 

`strSelect = "SELECT TOP 1 i.Code FROM [Item] AS i WHERE i.User = [which_user] ORDER BY i.ID`

would give me a SQL string with the fixed/non-variable [which_user] in the SQL, right?. And the
`qdf.Parameters("which_user").Value = strUserName`
would change this fixed [which_user] in the SQL string above?
What do I put in the double-quote instead of "which_user"? The [which_user] variable from the SQL string? Thank!

Comment: `which_user` is a parameter.  A query parameter is nothing more than a placeholder for a value which you must supply when the query is run.  It should make more sense if you paste the `SELECT` statement into SQL View of a new Access query and then run that query: `SELECT TOP 1 i.Code FROM [Item] AS i WHERE i.User = [which_user] ORDER BY i.ID DESC`

Comment: Thanks HansUp.
My problem is that I cannot manage to insert/change the variable "which_user" parameter into/in the strSelect. So my SQL string literally remains `strSelect = "SELECT TOP 1 i.Code FROM [Item] AS i WHERE i.User = [which_user] ORDER BY i.ID`. The [which_user] should be A_user right? So that the strSelect would be `strSelect = "SELECT TOP 1 i.Code FROM [Item] AS i WHERE i.User = 'A_user' ORDER BY i.ID` before the "qdf.OpenRecordSet", correct? 
Sorry, I am really a newbie:)

Comment: No, that's not correct.  But I'm unsure how to approach this now.  Have you tested the query in the Access query designer as I suggested yesterday?

Comment: Yes, I did. As I run the query, an input box pops up and I have to insert an user name for the parameter which_user. After insert the right user name into that box and click OK, I get the correct result.
Does it has something to do with my user name, which is the Windows user name fetched by using this function: 

`Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
    "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long`

For now, I still stuck at the `Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset`. The code run into an error there (Error 13, Type Mismatch)

Comment: I made a mistake on the second line.  `DAO.Database` was wrong.  I fixed it in answer: `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`  Sorry I didn't notice that until now.

Comment: It works like a champ! Thank you so much, @HansUp. You are the champ!

Answer (score 0):

Access sometimes complains about the use of single-quotes. And also add a semi-colon to the end of the statement. Try changing the code to this (where double-quotes are escaped with an extra double-quote:

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Item.Code FROM Item WHERE Item.User = " 
strSQL = strSQL & """" & strUserName & """" & " ORDER BY ID DESC;"
```

Comment: But as per DAXaholic's comment above, beware of SQL injection using this approach

Comment: I've tried these solutions but it did not help :(

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut15.htm

The `& """" & " ORDER BY ID DESC;"` in my strSQL is still cut off!

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo in the variable name `strSQL`? Also notice that my example assigns the variable on the first line, and then *appends* to the variable on the second (i.e. the variable appears on both sides of the `=` sign on the second line).